# How can I hook into the return values of either Model->all() or Model->get() in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say you have the following model:

```
// Model - Very basic
class VenueType extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "venue_types";        
}

// Database table
int id,
varchar(255) name,
varchar(255) address
```

From a controller, I would run something like this:

```
// Controller
$results = VenueType::all();
```

Is there anyway, within the model, to filter/hook (I'm hesitant to say filter, because of it's meaning in Laravel) the values. For example, add a title case function to the address (`ucwords`).

```
// Model
public function hookAddress(value) {
    return ucwords(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Eloquent Accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

```
class VenueType extends Eloquent {
protected $table = "venue_types";
    public function getAddressAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucwords($value);
    }

}
```